# Removing default Scroll bar from UWP app using XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my UWP app, I have a datagrid which already has a separate scroll bar but I am also getting the app default scroll bar which is I tried to hide and disable in following way:

```cs
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
```

but still on hovering I am getting a default scroll bar. Please refer to the attached image.

Could anyone help me in removing the default scroll bar?

[App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN2TG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml), it was not implemented with `ScrollViewer`,  we can't get the scrollviewer instance. for this scenario, you could detect vertical scrollbar with visual tree helper and hidden it, for more please refer the following code.

```
var scrollbar = MyFindDataGridChildOfType<ScrollBar>(MyDataGrid);
Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    scrollbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
});


public static T MyFindDataGridChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
{
    var MyQueue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    MyQueue.Enqueue(root);
    while (MyQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        DependencyObject current = MyQueue.Dequeue();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            var typedChild = child as T;
            if (typedChild != null)
            {
                return typedChild;
            }
            MyQueue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```